# Redirecting all non-local traffic from specific ip to external proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy

I currently have a squid proxy running on an external server (outside the LAN, with a public IP). I would like to route all non-local traffic from a specific device through it.

That is, any requests to the local NAT should not be forwarded, but anything else should be.

My iptables skills are mediocre to say the least, but i did find this which does what i want to some extent: [How can I redirect all traffic except local through external proxy with iptables in dd-wrt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90512/how-can-i-redirect-all-traffic-except-local-through-external-proxy-with-iptables)

However, i am unsure how to limit this to a specific ip, and if i might be forgetting some POSTROUTING, which other sites tell me is neccessary.

I will be setting this up on my router running dd-wrt.